# MSM defaults to login screen on Site 2

Tags: multi-site-manager

Have set up MSN as follows:

- spotlesslyclean.com
  -- system
  -- themes
  -- admin.php
  -- index.php
- spotlessovencleaning.co.uk
  -- admin.php
  -- index.php

However, when you visits spotlessovencleaning.co.uk, it defaults you to the login screen.

config file as follows:

```
    $system_path = '/var/www/vhosts/spotlesslyclean.com/dev.spotlesslyclean.com/system/';<br/>
$assign_to_config['site_name'] = 'spotless_oven_cleaning';<br/>
$assign_to_config['cp_url']    = 'http://dev.spotlessovencleaning.co.uk/admin.php';<br/>
$assign_to_config['site_url']  = 'http://dev.spotlessovencleaning.co.uk';<br/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved. I had managed to mix up my admin files.